# Xamarin forms List view not filling in Horizantal orientation

Tags: listview, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, fill

My Listview is filling half of the screen when I make some controls invisible.
The listview is in a grid control. Below is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.Converters;assembly=Sthotraani"
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.Behaviors;assembly=Sthotraani"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.CustomControls;assembly=Sthotraani"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.Views;assembly=Sthotraani"
             x:Class="Sthotraani.Views.GodsPage"  Title="Sthotraani" x:Name="pgGod" >
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <converters:ItemTappedEventArgsConverter x:Key="ItemTappedConverter" />
      <converters:BoolToImageConverter x:Key="booltoimage" />
      <converters:FileToImageConverter x:Key="FtoIConverter" />
      <converters:BoolToHeightConverter x:Key="BoolToHeight" />
      <converters:InvertBooleanConverter  x:Key="boolConvert"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="gMain" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ShowAd, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHeight},ConverterParameter=5|absolute}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ShowAd,Converter={StaticResource BoolToHeight},ConverterParameter=5|auto}"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <StackLayout x:Name="slMain" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" MinimumWidthRequest="1000" >
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#009688"  Padding="5" IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchVisisble}" Orientation="Horizontal" >
          <Entry x:Name="txtSearch" Text="{Binding SearchTerm}"  Placeholder="Enter sthotram name" PlaceholderColor="Gray"  FontSize="Micro"  TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView HeightRequest="5" BackgroundColor="White" IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchVisisble, Converter={StaticResource boolConvert}}" />
        <controls:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Gods}"
                               x:Name="cvGods"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGod}"
                               BackgroundColor="White"
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchVisisble, Converter={StaticResource boolConvert}}" >
          <controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <StackLayout Padding="5,0,5,0" >
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                  <StackLayout.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
                      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#B2DFDB"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="false">
                      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </StackLayout.Triggers>
                  <Image Source="{Binding ImageName,Converter={StaticResource FtoIConverter}}"   HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontSize="Micro"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
              </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
          </controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselView>
      </StackLayout>
      <ContentView
                  Grid.Row="0"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  VerticalOptions="Fill"
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                  BackgroundColor="#22009485"
                  Padding="10, 0">
        <ActivityIndicator VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           Color="#F98F1C"   />
      </ContentView>
      <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="bvTop"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HeightRequest="5"
               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></BoxView>
      <views:AdMobView WidthRequest="320"
                       HeightRequest="50"
                       x:Name="amvAds"
                       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"/>
      <BoxView BackgroundColor="#009688"
               x:Name="bvBottom"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HeightRequest="5"
               Grid.Row="3"
               Grid.Column="0"></BoxView>

      <ListView x:Name="lvSthotras"
                VerticalOptions="Start"
                SeparatorVisibility="None"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Sthotraas}"
                HasUnevenRows="True"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSthotram}"
                Grid.Row="4"
                Grid.Column="0">
        <ListView.Behaviors>
          <behaviors:ListViewSelectedItemBehavior Command="{Binding CmdListItemTapped}" Converter="{StaticResource ItemTappedConverter}" />
        </ListView.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <StackLayout>
                  <StackLayout Padding="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image HorizontalOptions="Start" Source="{Binding IsFavorite,Converter={StaticResource booltoimage},ConverterParameter=pickedstar.png|star.png}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                      <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CmdFavoriteTapped, Source={x:Reference pgGod}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SthotraID}" />
                      </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Label  Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"   FontSize="Small" />
                  </StackLayout>
                  <BoxView BackgroundColor="#009688"
                           HeightRequest="1"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
      <ContentView Grid.Row="4"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   VerticalOptions="Fill"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                   BackgroundColor="#22009485"
                   Padding="10, 0">
        <ActivityIndicator VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                           IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"
                           Color="#F98F1C"   />
      </ContentView>
    </Grid>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsVisible="{Binding IsOffline}" BackgroundColor="#009688">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Spacing="20" Padding="25">
      <Label FontSize="Large" TextColor="White"  >It seems you are not connected to internet, please check your network settings and click retry</Label>
      <Button Text="Retry" Command="{Binding CmdRetryNetwork}" Style="{StaticResource btn}"/>
    </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </Grid>
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Search" Command="{Binding ToggleSearchCmd}" Icon="{Binding IsSearchVisisble,Converter={StaticResource booltoimage},ConverterParameter=closeicon.png|SearchIcon.png}"  Order="Primary" Priority="1"  >
    </ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</views:BasePage>
```

Below is the part where I show are hide some controls

```
<StackLayout x:Name="slMain" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" MinimumWidthRequest="1000" >
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#009688"  Padding="5" IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchVisisble}" Orientation="Horizontal" >
          <Entry x:Name="txtSearch" Text="{Binding SearchTerm}"  Placeholder="Enter sthotram name" PlaceholderColor="Gray"  FontSize="Micro"  TextColor="Black" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView HeightRequest="5" BackgroundColor="White" IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchVisisble, Converter={StaticResource boolConvert}}" />
        <controls:CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding Gods}"
                               x:Name="cvGods"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGod}"
                               BackgroundColor="White"
                               IsVisible="{Binding IsSearchVisisble, Converter={StaticResource boolConvert}}" >
          <controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <StackLayout Padding="5,0,5,0" >
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                  <StackLayout.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true">
                      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#B2DFDB"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="false">
                      <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FFFFFF"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                  </StackLayout.Triggers>
                  <Image Source="{Binding ImageName,Converter={StaticResource FtoIConverter}}"   HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                       FontSize="Micro"
                       TextColor="Black"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
              </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
          </controls:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselView>
      </StackLayout>
```

Whenever I hide the carouselview above the listview will fill only half the screen. All the controls has HorizantalOptions="FillAndExpand" not sure what am I doing wrong. Below links videos will show you the behaviour

This is when the Device Orientation is vertical, everything works

https://youtu.be/aamFaiNpUE4

This is when device is horizantal, this is when listview acts weird.

https://youtu.be/DX2nFJnLn3o

Please help me.Thanks

Comment: You should probably use `"Fill"` for `HorizontalOptions` in those places, and also it does not make sense to have a single grid column with `Width="Auto"`. I would remove those column collections entirely - the default is to have a single column with width of `"*"` (which will fill the available space).

Comment: Earlier I have Width="*" I changed it thinking it will help, Also I thought fill and expand is more fool proof but will try fill. Thank you.

Comment: @keith Rome that worked very well, could you please tell the difference between Fill and FillAndExpand ?

Comment: Fill will resize to fit the container, without extending past the container's clipping size. FillAndExpand will resize to fit the container, but will also try to grow the container too, if it can.